# Writing Registry (WriteRegStr) in NSIS and Removing them in Uninstaller

Tags: nsis

I have an installer I am working on, where there could be multiple instances of the same product on a server.  For example, users may have a "test" instance, and a "live" instance installed.

It would be nice if the registry key for the product would be "product-test" and "product-live", so that in "Programs and Features", a user will be able to uninstall them separately.

I can do this, and it will create the keys in the registry...and it shows up properly in Programs and Features:

```
!define appname 'vpmapclient$Environment'
  
  ; Write the installation path and version into the registry
  WriteRegStr HKLM SOFTWARE\Company\${appname} "Install_Dir" "$INSTDIR"
  WriteRegStr HKLM SOFTWARE\Company\${appname} "DisplayVersion" "${_VERSION}"
  
  ; Write the uninstall keys for Windows
  WriteRegStr HKLM Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${appname} "DisplayName" "Company Product $Environment"
  WriteRegStr HKLM Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${appname} "Publisher" "Company"
  WriteRegStr HKLM Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${appname} "VersionMajor" ${VERSIONMAJOR}
  WriteRegStr HKLM Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${appname} "VersionMinor" ${VERSIONMINOR}
  WriteRegStr HKLM Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${appname} "Version" 0x02000000
  WriteRegStr HKLM Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${appname} "DisplayVersion" "${_VERSION}"
  WriteRegStr HKLM Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${appname} "UninstallString" '"$INSTDIR\product_uninstall.exe"'
  WriteRegStr HKLM Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${appname} "DisplayIcon" "$INSTDIR\Product.ico"
  WriteRegDWORD HKLM Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${appname} "EstimatedSize" "$EstimatedSize"
  WriteRegDWORD HKLM Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${appname} "NoModify" 1
  WriteRegDWORD HKLM Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${appname} "NoRepair" 1
  WriteUninstaller "$InstDir\product_uninstall.exe"
```

The issue is, that when I launch uninstall (that works fine from Programs and Features), it runs the uninstaller and it works...but the registry keys are NOT removed.

Here is the code from the uninstaller section:

```
 DetailPrint "===Removing Registry Keys for ${appname}==="
  ; Remove registry keys
  DeleteRegKey HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${appname}"
  DeleteRegKey HKLM "SOFTWARE\Company\${appname}"
```

The keys remain in the registry, and the entry remains in Programs and Features.  Despite the fact that the  uninstaller ran, executed the above DeleteRegKey and removed the program files and directories.

I did notice that if I do NOT use a variable, just a constant...that it works:

!define appname 'MyAppName'

Registry keys are properly removed.

Comment: I think I see what is happening...the variable isn't passed to the uninstaller.  A detailprint shows:  ===Removing Registry Keys for vpmapclient===   (the $Environment is not passed).       I wasn't expecting that, since $INSTDIR is used in the uninstaller, I assumed variables would be OK.

Answer (score 0):

The installer does not save anything automatically. In the uninstaller, $Instdir is just the uninstaller .exe directory.

In a case like this you can save the name in a .ini in $instdir and initialize from this .ini in `un.onInit`.

```
Section
SetOutPath $InstDir
WriteUninstaller "$InstDir\Uninst.exe"
WriteIniStr "$InstDir\Uninst.ini" "Storage" "Name" "$Environment"
SectionEnd

Function un.onInit
ReadIniStr $Environment "$InstDir\Uninst.ini" "Storage" "Name"
FunctionEnd
```